# How to align a pile of elements?

Tags: transforms

How can I align this pile of elements to the tree axis, in order they fit perfectly one on each other on X, Y, Z without gaps?

[image]

Comment: What I'm wondering is why you have a lot of the same objects but not in the same place? How did this happen? I would just keep one of them and then use an array modifier. Or are they slightly different so it is important to keep them all individually? Because then the given answer might not work properly.

Comment: They are the same in terms of width and depth, but slightly different in height, therefore I needed to keep them individually, otherwise I would have been using an Array modifier.

Comment: F3, set origin to geometry, then set $xy$ coordinates to 0?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the two objects are equals and parallel each other.

Choose two vertices belonging to the planes that should match, enable vertex snapping type, select the top object, press <kbd>G</kbd>, then <kbd>B</kbd>, then click on vertex A, then click on vertex B.

Works only on 4.0 version and above.

[image]

Another method is using an Array modifier, set Relative offset of 1 on Z axis (make sure you applied the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: I already know Vertex snap, which was introduced previously to Blender 4.0, may I ask you why you mention "it works only on Version 4.0 and above", do they made any change in snap option? I do apologise but I am very new to Blender, therefore would like to learn more.

Comment: @CarloVentimiglia You might know the simple vertex snap, but if you follow his instructions you'll see that he starts moving, then presses B and select vertices on each object which should snap to each other. That is a new feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.